# Javascript - cart only adds 1 item one even if 2 or 5 the item are buyed

Tags: javascript, shopping-cart, cart

My script is in just HTML and Javascript and I can't find what's wrong. I have a html-page that contains 8 products all with the same html-style. But when I click on product 2 or 8 it always only list the first product on the list. And I can't figure out what I need to do to get it to work. (some text in scripts are in my home language Swedish)

HTML code

```
 <div id="Tama">
  <h2>TAMA</h2>
  <img src="images/trummor/tama.jpg">
  <br/>
  <p>TAMA Superstar. </p>
  <p>Pris: 25000 kr</p>
  <hr style="border: 1px solid #000;">
  <form name="order">
   <input type="hidden" id="IDnumber" value="004">
   <input type="hidden" id="pris" value="25000">
   <input type="hidden" id="item" value="Tama Superstar">
   Välj antal: 
   <input type="text" id="antal" value="1" name="antal"  onChange="this.value=CKquantity(this.value)" style="width:30px;" maxlength="1"> | 
   <input type="button" value="Köp" onclick="addElement(this.form);">
  </form>
  <hr style="border: 1px solid #000;">
  <p>
   <a href="#drums" onclick="drums()">Tillbaka till produkter</a>
  </p>
 </div>
```

Javascript Cart File

```
// -- CHECK IF ANTAL IS A NUMBER -- //
function CKquantity(checkString) {
  var strNewQuantity = "";

  for ( i = 0; i < checkString.length; i++ ) {
  ch = checkString.substring(i, i+1);
  if ( (ch >= "0" && ch <= "9") || (ch == '.') )
     strNewQuantity += ch;
  }

  if ( strNewQuantity.length < 1 )
  strNewQuantity = "1";

  return(strNewQuantity);
 }

 // -- ADD TO CART -- //
 // still problem - only enter the first item on the list either you click on the
  second or last product

function addElement(thisForm)
 { 
var itemId = document.getElementById('IDnumber').value
var itemName = document.getElementById('item').innerHTML;

var antal = document.getElementById('antal').value;
var pris = document.getElementById('pris').value;

var parent = document.getElementById('cart'); 
var newElement = document.createElement('li'); 
newElement.setAttribute('class','item');

var sum = antal * pris;

newElement.innerHTML = "("+itemId+") "+ antal + " x " + itemName + " - " + pris + " kr, Totalt: " + sum + " kr";
parent.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

Comment: Did you hear something about case sensitivity in JS ?

Comment: HTML IDs have to be unique ... you should give every item a different id (e.g. `item_111` with the item id or so instead of only `item`)

Comment: yeep, but didin't know that i'd have to have it all.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is Case Sensitive scripting language, which means its keywords should be written in the `right-case`. You should write `function` instead of `FUNCTION`.

Try This:

```
function addElement()
{ 
var itemName = document.getElementById('item').innerHTML;
var antal = document.getElementById('antal').value; // 'value' not 'VALUE'

var parent = document.getElementById('cart'); 
var newElement = document.createElement('li'); 
newElement.setAttribute('class','item'); 
newElement.innerHTML = antal + " x " + itemName; 
parent.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

Comment: Your `document.getElementById('antal').VALUE` will be undefined, cause, as you already wrote - Js is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanx!

It works, but how do I get it to enter individual objects instead of on same object in the cart. Now it lists the first product even if I klick buy (köp) on the last product. Or shall I say look after id "item" and then like use id with item_111, item_222 and so on.

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what you trying to ask can you explain it a bit more with some example if required (you can add this in your question). If you are asking how to iterate over different objects in page than you can do this by specifying their respective `unique-IDs` with `document.getElementById('IDHere');`

Comment: Sajjad: I've edited the Q and on the topyou can see the new thing.

Comment: As your real question has been answered and your new question is of totally new nature  so I advise you to `mark this answer as Answer` and post new question over stack overflow for your next query that would also help the community, otherwise title/question/answer will totally get misleading. Thankyou.